# how to combine two 2d arrays horizontally in java withdifferent dimensions

Tags: java, arrays

I have been given 2 2d arrays something like below and I want to combine them

```
     a       b      combine(a,b)   combine(b,a)
  1 1 1     3 3     1 1 1 3 3    3 3 1 1 1
  2 2 2     4 4     2 2 2 4 4    4 4 2 2 2
            5 5     0 0 0 5 5    5 5 0 0 0
```

I am trying something like below ,but I am getting confused about it

```
import java.util.Arrays; 



class Main {

  public static int[] [] combine(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    System.out.println(a[0].length+b[0].length);
        int[][] c = new int[a[0].length+b[0].length][b[1].length];

        for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length+b[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[1].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("a "+a[i][j]);
              if(i>a[0].length)
              {
                c[i][j]=b[i][j]
              }

             
                 
            }
        }
      return c;
    }
    
  

  public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[][] a = new int[][] {{1,1,1}, {2,2, 2}};
        int[][] b = new int[][] {{3,3}, {4, 4},{5,5}};

combine( a,  b);
/*
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(combine( a,  b))
                         .replace("],","\n").replace(",","\t| ")
                         .replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", " "));
                         */
  }
  
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decomposing the problem:

First figure out the dimensions of the new array. Assuming that both input arrays are rectangular (not jagged), the combined array will have as many rows as whichever one of the input array that has more rows, and will have as many columns as the sum of the number of columns of the input arrays. Therefore,

```
int[][] c = new int[Math.max(a.length, b.length)][a[0].length + b[0].length];
```

Then, the first input array can be filled into `c` just like normal:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
        c[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
}
```

The second input array needs to be *offset* by a few places. Exactly how many places? The number of columns in the first input array:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < b.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < b[0].length ; j++) {
        c[i][j + a[0].length] = b[i][j];
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

And that's it!

```
public static int[] [] combine(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    System.out.println(a[0].length+b[0].length);
    int[][] c = new int[Math.max(a.length, b.length)][a[0].length + b[0].length];

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < b.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < b[0].length ; j++) {
            c[i][j + a[0].length] = b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to calculate the size of the result array and then populate it with values from `a` and `b` separately:

```java
public static int[] [] combine(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int cols = a[0].length+b[0].length;
    int rows = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    System.out.println("Result: rows=" + rows + ", columns=" + cols);
    
    int[][] c = new int[rows][cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = a[0].length; j < cols; j++) {  column index in the result shifted
            c[i][j] = b[i][j - a[0].length];
        }
    }
    
    for (int[] row : c) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
    return c;
}
```

Test:

```java
int[][] a = new int[][] {{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}};
int[][] b = new int[][] {{3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5}};

combine(a,  b);
combine(b,  a);
```

Output:

```
Result: rows=3, columns=5
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 4, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 5, 5]
Result: rows=3, columns=5
[3, 3, 1, 1, 1]
[4, 4, 2, 2, 2]
[5, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```